# Как заменить запятую на точку

Tags: python, python-3.x

В парсере валют нужно заменить запятую на точку, как это сделать?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

DOLLAR_UAH = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80+%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0&oq=%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80+%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0i20i263i512j0i512l8.2878j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.75 Safari/537.36'}


def dollar_uah():
    full_page = requests.get (DOLLAR_UAH, headers=headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(full_page.content, 'html.parser')

    convert = soup.findAll("span", {"class" : "DFlfde", "class" : "SwHCTb", "data-precision": 2})

    print(convert[0].text) 

dollar_uah()
```

Comment: Один только вопрос. Нахрена при наличии ниипического количества ресурсов с API для получения всевозможных курсов костылять парсер гугла для этой цели?

Comment: Я по гайду делал, а на других сайтах тяжко находить контент в коде елемента за что зацепиться. А в гугле легко и привычно как-то.

Comment: https://bank.gov.ua/NBUStatService/v1/statdirectory/exchange?json

Comment: Я в питоне недели 2, а ты мне уже какие-то json файлы кидаешь

Comment: Ну ты, братка, даешь ))) Парсить гугл через 2 недели норм а один из базовых форматов обмена данными (которы к слову без усилий приводится к словарю) тебе сложно. Удачи бро )))))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если это нужно сделать для этой строки:

```
convert[0].text
```

то при помощи метода replace(что_замнить, на_что)

```
convert[0].text.replace(",", ".")
```

Comment: Спасибо, очень выручили

Answer (score 0):

Один только вопрос. Нахрена при наличии ниипического количества ресурсов с API для получения всевозможных курсов костылять парсер гугла для этой цели?
К примеру:

```py
import requests

response = requests.get('https://bank.gov.ua/NBUStatService/v1/statdirectory/exchange?json')

print(
    response.json()
)
```

```json
[{
        "r030": 36,
        "txt": "Австралійський долар",
        "rate": 21.8227,
        "cc": "AUD",
        "exchangedate": "11.04.2022"
    }, {
        "r030": 124,
        "txt": "Канадський долар",
        "rate": 23.2357,
        "cc": "CAD",
        "exchangedate": "11.04.2022"
    }, {
        "r030": 156,
        "txt": "Юань Женьміньбі",
        "rate": 4.5972,
        "cc": "CNY",
        "exchangedate": "11.04.2022"
    }, {
        "r030": 191,
        "txt": "Куна",
        "rate": 4.2069,
        "cc": "HRK",
        "exchangedate": "11.04.2022"
    }, {
        "r030": 203,
        "txt": "Чеська крона",
        "rate": 1.2979,
        "cc": "CZK",
        "exchangedate": "11.04.2022"
    }, {
        "r030": 208,
        "txt": "Данська крона",
        "rate": 4.2731,
        "cc": "DKK",
        "exchangedate": "11.04.2022"
    }, {
        "r030": 344,
        "txt": "Гонконгівський долар",
        "rate": 3.7322,
        "cc": "HKD",
        "exchangedate": "11.04.2022"
    }, {
        "r030": 348,
        "txt": "Форинт",
        "rate": 0.084559,
        "cc": "HUF",
        "exchangedate": "11.04.2022"
    }, {
        "r030": 356,
        "txt": "Індійська рупія",
        "rate": 0.38547,
        "cc": "INR",
        "exchangedate": "11.04.2022"
    }, {
        "r030": 360,
        "txt": "Рупія",
        "rate": 0.002037,
        "cc": "IDR",
        "exchangedate": "11.04.2022"
    }, {
        "r030": 376,
        "txt": "Новий ізраїльський шекель",
        "rate": 9.0741,
        "cc": "ILS",
        "exchangedate": "11.04.2022"
    }, {
        "r030": 392,
        "txt": "Єна",
        "rate": 0.23558,
        "cc": "JPY",
        "exchangedate": "11.04.2022"
    }, {
        "r030": 398,
        "txt": "Теньге",
        "rate": 0.065878,
        "cc": "KZT",
        "exchangedate": "11.04.2022"
    }, {
        "r030": 410,
        "txt": "Вона",
        "rate": 0.023876,
        "cc": "KRW",
        "exchangedate": "11.04.2022"
    }, {
        "r030": 484,
        "txt": "Мексиканське песо",
        "rate": 1.4521,
        "cc": "MXN",
        "exchangedate": "11.04.2022"
    }, {
        "r030": 498,
        "txt": "Молдовський лей",
        "rate": 1.5927,
        "cc": "MDL",
        "exchangedate": "11.04.2022"
    }, {
        "r030": 554,
        "txt": "Новозеландський долар",
        "rate": 20.0469,
        "cc": "NZD",
        "exchangedate": "11.04.2022"
    }, {
        "r030": 578,
        "txt": "Норвезька крона",
        "rate": 3.3444,
        "cc": "NOK",
        "exchangedate": "11.04.2022"
    }, {
        "r030": 643,
        "txt": "Російський рубль",
        "rate": 0.37819,
        "cc": "RUB",
        "exchangedate": "11.04.2022"
    }, {
        "r030": 682,
        "txt": "Саудівський ріял",
        "rate": 7.8009,
        "cc": "SAR",
        "exchangedate": "11.04.2022"
    }, {
        "r030": 702,
        "txt": "Сінгапурський долар",
        "rate": 21.4636,
        "cc": "SGD",
        "exchangedate": "11.04.2022"
    }, {
        "r030": 710,
        "txt": "Ренд",
        "rate": 1.987,
        "cc": "ZAR",
        "exchangedate": "11.04.2022"
    }, {
        "r030": 752,
        "txt": "Шведська крона",
        "rate": 3.0922,
        "cc": "SEK",
        "exchangedate": "11.04.2022"
    }, {
        "r030": 756,
        "txt": "Швейцарський франк",
        "rate": 31.2903,
        "cc": "CHF",
        "exchangedate": "11.04.2022"
    }, {
        "r030": 818,
        "txt": "Єгипетський фунт",
        "rate": 1.595,
        "cc": "EGP",
        "exchangedate": "11.04.2022"
    }, {
        "r030": 826,
        "txt": "Фунт стерлінгів",
        "rate": 38.1133,
        "cc": "GBP",
        "exchangedate": "11.04.2022"
    }, {
        "r030": 840,
        "txt": "Долар США",
        "rate": 29.2549,
        "cc": "USD",
        "exchangedate": "11.04.2022"
    }, {
        "r030": 933,
        "txt": "Білоруський рубль",
        "rate": 10.6335,
        "cc": "BYN",
        "exchangedate": "11.04.2022"
    }, {
        "r030": 946,
        "txt": "Румунський лей",
        "rate": 6.4295,
        "cc": "RON",
        "exchangedate": "11.04.2022"
    }, {
        "r030": 949,
        "txt": "Турецька ліра",
        "rate": 1.9829,
        "cc": "TRY",
        "exchangedate": "11.04.2022"
    }, {
        "r030": 960,
        "txt": "СПЗ (спеціальні права запозичення)",
        "rate": 40.0873,
        "cc": "XDR",
        "exchangedate": "11.04.2022"
    }, {
        "r030": 975,
        "txt": "Болгарський лев",
        "rate": 16.2527,
        "cc": "BGN",
        "exchangedate": "11.04.2022"
    }, {
        "r030": 978,
        "txt": "Євро",
        "rate": 31.7796,
        "cc": "EUR",
        "exchangedate": "11.04.2022"
    }, {
        "r030": 985,
        "txt": "Злотий",
        "rate": 6.8442,
        "cc": "PLN",
        "exchangedate": "11.04.2022"
    }, {
        "r030": 12,
        "txt": "Алжирський динар",
        "rate": 0.20515,
        "cc": "DZD",
        "exchangedate": "11.04.2022"
    }, {
        "r030": 50,
        "txt": "Така",
        "rate": 0.33938,
        "cc": "BDT",
        "exchangedate": "11.04.2022"
    }, {
        "r030": 51,
        "txt": "Вірменський драм",
        "rate": 0.060206,
        "cc": "AMD",
        "exchangedate": "11.04.2022"
    }, {
        "r030": 364,
        "txt": "Іранський ріал",
        "rate": 0.00069655,
        "cc": "IRR",
        "exchangedate": "11.04.2022"
    }, {
        "r030": 368,
        "txt": "Іракський динар",
        "rate": 0.020038,
        "cc": "IQD",
        "exchangedate": "11.04.2022"
    }, {
        "r030": 417,
        "txt": "Сом",
        "rate": 0.35477,
        "cc": "KGS",
        "exchangedate": "11.04.2022"
    }, {
        "r030": 422,
        "txt": "Ліванський фунт",
        "rate": 0.019406,
        "cc": "LBP",
        "exchangedate": "11.04.2022"
    }, {
        "r030": 434,
        "txt": "Лівійський динар",
        "rate": 6.3013,
        "cc": "LYD",
        "exchangedate": "11.04.2022"
    }, {
        "r030": 458,
        "txt": "Малайзійський ринггіт",
        "rate": 6.9601,
        "cc": "MYR",
        "exchangedate": "11.04.2022"
    }, {
        "r030": 504,
        "txt": "Марокканський дирхам",
        "rate": 3.029,
        "cc": "MAD",
        "exchangedate": "11.04.2022"
    }, {
        "r030": 586,
        "txt": "Пакистанська рупія",
        "rate": 0.1592,
        "cc": "PKR",
        "exchangedate": "11.04.2022"
    }, {
        "r030": 704,
        "txt": "Донг",
        "rate": 0.001281,
        "cc": "VND",
        "exchangedate": "11.04.2022"
    }, {
        "r030": 764,
        "txt": "Бат",
        "rate": 0.87963,
        "cc": "THB",
        "exchangedate": "11.04.2022"
    }, {
        "r030": 784,
        "txt": "Дирхам ОАЕ",
        "rate": 7.9649,
        "cc": "AED",
        "exchangedate": "11.04.2022"
    }, {
        "r030": 788,
        "txt": "Туніський динар",
        "rate": 9.8951,
        "cc": "TND",
        "exchangedate": "11.04.2022"
    }, {
        "r030": 860,
        "txt": "Узбецький сум",
        "rate": 0.0025673,
        "cc": "UZS",
        "exchangedate": "11.04.2022"
    }, {
        "r030": 934,
        "txt": "Туркменський новий манат",
        "rate": 8.3585,
        "cc": "TMT",
        "exchangedate": "11.04.2022"
    }, {
        "r030": 941,
        "txt": "Сербський динар",
        "rate": 0.27586,
        "cc": "RSD",
        "exchangedate": "11.04.2022"
    }, {
        "r030": 944,
        "txt": "Азербайджанський манат",
        "rate": 17.2433,
        "cc": "AZN",
        "exchangedate": "11.04.2022"
    }, {
        "r030": 972,
        "txt": "Сомоні",
        "rate": 2.2573,
        "cc": "TJS",
        "exchangedate": "11.04.2022"
    }, {
        "r030": 981,
        "txt": "Ларі",
        "rate": 9.5417,
        "cc": "GEL",
        "exchangedate": "11.04.2022"
    }, {
        "r030": 986,
        "txt": "Бразильський реал",
        "rate": 6.1308,
        "cc": "BRL",
        "exchangedate": "11.04.2022"
    }, {
        "r030": 959,
        "txt": "Золото",
        "rate": 56553.23,
        "cc": "XAU",
        "exchangedate": "11.04.2022"
    }, {
        "r030": 961,
        "txt": "Срібло",
        "rate": 720.3,
        "cc": "XAG",
        "exchangedate": "11.04.2022"
    }, {
        "r030": 962,
        "txt": "Платина",
        "rate": 28271.06,
        "cc": "XPT",
        "exchangedate": "11.04.2022"
    }, {
        "r030": 964,
        "txt": "Паладій",
        "rate": 67506.85,
        "cc": "XPD",
        "exchangedate": "11.04.2022"
    }
]
```